# Flex 4 bug:inherited propery cause transition bug

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

i try to make some foldable groups, like an accordion component
i create a Base.as class and extends from Group,code like this

```
package
{
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import spark.components.Group;
public class Base extends Group
{
    public var header:Group;
    public var body:Group;
    public function Base()
    {
        super();
    }
    override protected function initializationComplete():void
    {
        super.initializationComplete();
        if(header)
        {
            header.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,changeState);
        }
    }
    protected function changeState(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(currentState=="fold")
            currentState="unfold";
        else
            currentState="fold";
    }
}
}
```

and i defined two properties,header and body here,but i don't instantiate here,and then i worte a mxml component "FoldUnit.mxml" that extends "Base" and i will instantiate header and body in it,code like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<local:Base xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" currentState="fold" clipAndEnableScrolling="true"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:local="*" width="200" >
<local:states>
    <s:State name="fold" />
    <s:State name="unfold" />
</local:states>
<local:transitions>
    <s:Transition toState="fold">
        <s:Sequence>
            <s:Resize target="{this}" duration="400" />
            <s:RemoveAction target="{body}" />
        </s:Sequence>
    </s:Transition>
    <s:Transition toState="unfold">
            <s:Resize target="{this}" duration="400" />
    </s:Transition>
</local:transitions>
<s:Group id="header" width="100%">
    <s:Rect height="40" width="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xff0000" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
<s:Group id="body" includeIn="unfold" y="40" width="100%">
    <s:Rect height="200" width="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0x00ff00" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
</local:Base>
```

after all,i placed three of FoldUnit in main application to simulate an accordion component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:local="*">
<s:Group>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout variableRowHeight="true" />
    </s:layout>
    <local:FoldUnit />
    <local:FoldUnit />
    <local:FoldUnit />
</s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

everything like fine,however,if i try to click one red header to fold up,that green body just disappear immediately,looks like that RemoveAction tag is useless.

so,as i try to figure out why,i made things simple first,and i combine that function in Base.as into FoldUnit.mxml,then it works fine.

so,i wonder is there a bug or something?
PS:i don't wanna use a skinable component,coz' the size measure process always delayed,it's hard to location the scroll position in scroll bar.

Comment: Damn, I was gonna say you should use skinning instead of code-behind ;) If a collapsible panel is what you're after, you might be interested in the one I created: https://github.com/RIAstar/CollapsiblePanelFx

Comment: hey,thanks for your reply.
what i want to do is make something like tool bar in picmonkey.com.
it can auto scroll to where expanded.